# Trouble understanding linear independence when you don't have numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stumped when it comes to the following problem:

Suppose that vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are such that $−8v_1+5v_2=−6v_3$. Are the three vectors linearly independent?

I understand how to determine linear independence when you have vectors with numbers and such (without coefficients) by either using Row Reduction or finding the determinant, but with the above case I have no clue where to start. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start with the definition. What does it mean for a set of vectors to be linearly independent?

Comment: If their vectors have coefficients that are all zero, correct?

Comment: No. A set of vectors is said to be linearly independent if no vector in the set can be written as a linear combination of the others. Equivalently, we say that $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly independent if for some scalars $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ we have $c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n=0$, then it must be that $c_1=\cdots=c_n=0$.

Comment: That is what I meant. Instead of coefficients I should have said scalars.

Comment: So, because the scalars are not all 0 in the above problem, this means that the three vectors must be linearly dependent?

Comment: Yes! The relationship you are given between the vectors indicates that $-8v_1+5v_2+6v_3=0$, which violates the definition of linear independence.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that a set of vectors is linear dependent if and only if one of its elements can be written as a linear combination of other elements. So in your assumption the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linear dependent.

In other words you have to consider $v_1, v_2,\frac{−8}{-6}v_1+\frac{5}{-6}v_2$
which is clearly linear dependent.

Comment: While this isn't circular logic, it is strange to appeal to "well known" facts when the problem can be solved just as easily using only the definition of linear dependence.